# operator overloading() in c++

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

can someone explain to me what does this code do in c++ program? I know this is operator overloading but what exactly this type of overloading is used for? Thank you in advance.

```
class CLess {
public:
 bool operator()(const T& x, const T& y)const { return x < y; }
};
```

Comment: It makes an object of a class callable, like a function returning `bool`

Comment: _"but what exactly this type of overloading is used for?"_ Eg. to be passed as comparator for `std::sort()` functions.